# Running subl in El Capitan produces the error 'The application /Applications/Sublime Text.app cannot be opened because its executable is missing.'

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, osx-elcapitan

I upgraded to El Capitan yesterday lo and behold my `~/bin` folder had been blown away. So I followed the standard tip to link `subl` to `/usr/local/bin` with the command

```
ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Nevertheless now I get the error

```
The application /Applications/Sublime Text.app cannot 
be opened because its executable is missing.
```

Anybody else experience this/know the solution?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Sublime?

Comment: Worked. I feel dumb. Thanks!